# How to declare individual elements in a enum in java?

Tags: java, collections, enums

Hi I am trying to write this piece of code about physics but have a problem.

In fact two problems:
1.the formula for gravitation its throwing a error about using the field .class
2.I want to declare the types of individual variables in a element
I think its clearer if I show the source code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    abstract class Gravitation{
        public abstract int Gravitation(int mass[],int dist,int force);
    }
    class PhySyst{
        public int mass;
        public int wt;
        public float smallG = 9.8f;
        //this is the posible value of charge
        enum Charge{Positive,Negative,PositiveCoulumb,NegativeCoulumb,IsNegative,IsPositive};
        
        
    }
    class Earth extends Gravitation{
        //stores acceleration due to gravity
        public float smallG = 9.8f;
        //the raduis of earth is needed in the physics formula for distance
        public float GravityPressure = 6.67f;
        public float raduisofEarth = 6371f;
        //this finds the gravation using newtons principles
        public int Gravitation(int mass[],int dist,int force)
        {
            force = (GravityPressure * mass[])/(dist * dist);
            return force;
        }
    }
}
```

the error is this:

```
Main.java:32: error: '.class' expected
            force = (GravityPressure * mass[])/(dist * dist);
                                             ^
1 error
```

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of Fixes here:

1. Constants should be `static final` (#constant).
2. Gm1m2/r2, formula so rather than array you should pass 2 input params (m1 and m2).
3. As multiplication is operation for number not array (`mass[]`).
4. `Enum` should be defined in **public class or in static class.**
5. As the force can be float, so change the return type to `float` from current `int`.

---

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Category {

  abstract class Gravitation {

    public abstract float getGravitationalForce(int mass1, int mass2, int dist);
  }

  //this is the possible value of charge
  enum Charge {
    Positive, Negative, PositiveCoulumb, NegativeCoulumb, IsNegative, IsPositive
  };

  class PhySyst {

    public int mass;

    public int wt;

    public float smallG = 9.8f;

  }

  class Earth extends Gravitation {

    //stores acceleration due to gravity
    public static final float SMALL_G = 9.8f; #constant

    //the radius of earth is needed in the physics formula for distance
    public static final float GRAVITATIONAL_PRESSURE = 6.67f; #constant

    public static final float RADIUS_OF_EARTH = 6371f; #constant

    //this finds the gravitation using newtons principles
    public float getGravitationalForce(int mass1, int mass2, int dist) {
      return (GRAVITATIONAL_PRESSURE * mass1 * mass2) / (dist * dist);
    }
  }

}
```